# about folder under subfolder using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, file, directory

i want to delete all the  under root folder e:\trichy.root folder contain also sub folder like e:\trichy\chn\20008\20204*.mp3 files. pls help me . always getting an error.

```
Dim rootfolder1 As FileInfo
    rootfolder1 = txtRootFolder.Text

    Try
        If Directory.Exists(rootfolder1) Then

            Dim files() As String = Directory.GetDirectories(rootfolder1)
            For Each file As String In files
                Dim fi As FileInfo = New FileInfo(file)
                If (fi.LastAccessTime < DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3)) Then
                    fi.Delete()
                    display_status("files are deleted successfully")
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        display_status("Error in file deletion" & ex.Message)
    End Try
```

pls help me to delete files under this root folder under subfolder?

Comment: Why didn't you post the error details? Should we be guessing?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the FileInfo objects at all. I have not tested, but it may just be an unnecessary waste or resources, and expensive performancewise.

Try this:

```
Private Sub DeleteOldFiles(ByVal rootFolder As String, ByVal uptoDate As Date, Optional ByVal fileTypes As String = "*.*")
    Try
        If Directory.Exists(rootFolder) Then
            Dim files() As String = Directory.GetFiles(rootFolder, fileTypes, SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            For Each f As String In files
                If File.GetLastAccessTime(f) <= uptoDate Then
                    File.Delete(f)
                End If
            Next
        End If
        display_status("files are deleted successfully")
    Catch ex As Exception
        display_status("Error in file deletion" & ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Usage:

```
DeleteOldFiles(txtRootFolder.Text, Now.AddMonths(-3), "*.mp3")
```

Answer (score 0):

Deletes the specified directory and, if indicated, any subdirectories and files in the directory.

```
  Directory.Delete(Path1, true)
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.delete.aspx)

Comment: But he wants to delete only files older than 3 months.

Comment: his question title was confusing and `i want to delete all the under root folder` too, now i get it

Answer (score 0):

`Directory.GetDirectories` returns all sub-directories. Then you're creating `FileInfo` objects from it.

I assume that you instead want to delete the files in that folder, than you need to use [`Directory.GetFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx):

```
Dim files() As String = Directory.GetFiles(rootfolder1)
For Each file As String In files
    Dim fi As FileInfo = New FileInfo(file)
    If (fi.LastAccessTime < DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3)) Then
        fi.Delete()
    End If
Next
display_status("files are deleted successfully")
```

If you want to delete all files in all sub-folders recursively:

```
Public Shared Sub ProcessDirectory(ByVal targetDirectory As String)
    Dim fileEntries As String() = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory)
    Dim fileName As String
    For Each fileName In fileEntries
        Dim fi As FileInfo = New FileInfo(fileName)
        If (fi.LastAccessTime < DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3)) Then
            fi.Delete()
        End If
    Next fileName

    Dim subdirectoryEntries As String() = Directory.GetDirectories(targetDirectory)
    ' Recurse into subdirectories of this directory.
    Dim subdirectory As String
    For Each subdirectory In subdirectoryEntries
        ProcessDirectory(subdirectory)
    Next subdirectory
End Sub
```

You would call it:

```
ProcessDirectory(rootfolder1)
```